# Side-limit of $f(x)=\frac{x^2\cdot\lfloor x\rfloor}{|x-1|}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem wants the value of left hand limit of the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{x^2\cdot\lfloor x\rfloor}{|x-1|}$ when $x\to3^-$.I graphed the function and the answer is $\frac{3}{2}$ but what's wrong with my method:

For any value $x\to3^-$ we have $[x]=2$ , $|x-1|=x-1$ so if $h\to0^-$, then $f(3+h)=\frac{2(3+h)^2}{2+h}=\frac{2h^2+12h+18}{2+h}$. So the value of the derivative is equal to:
$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\dfrac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{\frac{2h^2+12h+18}{2+h}-\frac{27}{2}}{h}$$ which is infinity and clearly wrong with or without the graph. I'm not new into this but I can't figure out what's wrong here despite I thought about the method for one hour straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got the problem. In the following figure the green graph is $f(x)$ and the red one is $f'(x)$. Now if you calculate the left hand limit of the derivative using $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0^-}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, you're actually calculating the slope of the line that **approaches** to the segment $AB$ which **is** infinity so we're not wrong on this point.

[image]

The major problem about this method is that we actually want the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ when we're still before $x=3$. For doing that simply note that for $x\in(2,3)$ which contains the left neighborhoods of $x=3$, $f(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x-1}$ and this function's derivative in $x=3$ is exactly equal to $\frac{2}{3}$.

Furthermore, if you insist on solving this with the definition of derivative one can modify the formula like the following: (the following form is clearly a more general definition that will also work for the discontinuity points)
$$\displaystyle {f'_\pm} (x)=\lim_{h\to0^{\pm}}\bigg(\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\dfrac{f(x+h+t)-f(x+t)}{h}\bigg)$$
In which we shift the points in the wanted direction first, and then do the rest.

*P.S. The segment $AB$ is not a part of the graph. I added it myself

Comment: Nice job coming up with a definition for the "left left derivative" you wanted. Note that it's equivalent to $\lim_{t\to x^-}f'(t)$ (using the standard definition of $f'$).

Comment: Yeah you're right there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with you that the answer is 3/2. The left hand limit is +inf, and the right hand limit is -inf, as you can see if you graph the function of the derivative.

Comment: Guys go ahead and check it out on Desmos. It is 3/2

Comment: The right hand derivative is to me 9/4.

Comment: @gpassante you're right but I wanted the left hand derivative

Comment: @Aryaaaaan As you correctly calculated, the left hand derivative is $+\infty$.

Comment: @gpassante as you surely know, left hand derivative is the derivative in the left neighborhood of $3$, so it doesn't matter that $f(3)\not=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to3^-}f(x)$ since we're going to take the limit of the derivative in the left neighborhood of $3$ anyways. And if you look at the graph of the function I linked in my post, the value is clearly not infinity.

Comment: @Aryaaaaan $f'_-(3)$ and $\lim_{x\to3^-}f'(x)$ are **different** things. A simple calculation give

$$f'_-(3)=+\infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{x\to 3^-}f'(x)=3/2. $$

Comment: I guess you're confused here. Aside from the the mathematical notation **derivative**, by definition the "left hand derivative" means the value of the slope of the line tangent to the graph of the function $f(x)$ when the point of tangency gets closer and closer to $x$ from the left. Now by this definition, you have to take the slope of the line tangent to the graph of the function **before** reaching $x=3$. But what (in my opinion) you're doing wrong is that you're using the mathematical definition of **derivative** that calculates the slope of the line connecting B to a point approaching A.

Comment: As I have already explained, what you describe is the **limit** of the derivative when the point approaches 3 from the left. Another thing is the value of the left derivative **at** 3. If it were as you say, every derivative function would be continuous (at least on the left in the present case). And therefore the space of the differentiable functions would coincide with that of the functions of class $C^1$. But, coincidentally, these two spaces are different. And their diversity is the basis of many Analysis theorems.

Comment: Oh I just checked my post twice. You're right about that. I had typed left hand derivative instead of left hand limit of derivative. Corrected it

Comment: I'm glad that this is cleared up. Bye and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2\cdot\lfloor x\rfloor}{|x-1|}$$

Assume $0 \le \delta < 1$. Then

\begin{align}
   f(3)&= 13.5\\
   f(3-\delta) &= 9 \\
\hline
   f'(3^-) 
   &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\dfrac{f(3) - f(3-\delta)}{3 - (3-\delta)} \\
   &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\dfrac{f(3) - f(3-\delta)}{3 - (3-\delta)} \\
   &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\dfrac{4.5}{\delta} \\
   &= \infty
\end{align}

You did it correctly. Why? Because the floor function is discontinuous from below.

$f(3^-) = 9$ and $f(3) = f(3^+) = 13.5$

Comment: @Aryaaaaan: No $f(3^-) = \dfrac{9 \times 2}{2}=9$.